# ORACLE SQL and limitation of multiple returns from COMMENT ON TABLE

Tags: sql, oracle, comments

How can I get

```
COMMENT ON TABLE  Table.ABC IS 'Blah 1';
COMMENT ON TABLE  Table.ABC IS 'Blah 2';
```

To return

```
Table.ABC Blah 1

Table.ABC Blah 2
```

Instead of only returning one comment (the last one)

```
Table.ABC Blah 2
```

by calling below query

```
 SELECT table_name, comments

 FROM user_tab_comments

 WHERE comments IS NOT NULL

 ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

Comment: I think you can add only one comment on a table. Why do you want to add multiple comments? Can you use multi-line comment?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't. You can have only one comment per object.
2. If for some reason you need to you can always create your own table and have as many comments as you want.